# Restructuring data in python

Tags: python

So I have a dataset with multiple columns and rows. I am interested in trimming the dataset such that I would only want this one variable from the 2nd colummn to be present, and all the other variables in that column to be removed. At the same time, I would want all the remaining columns and rows to be kept. This would effectively make a new dataset whereby my 2nd column is just that one variable, and its respective values corresponding to the other columns. How do I do this in python?

I tried this through the aid of chatgpt but its difficult